# What is the best practice for logging debug and trace messages in Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

The Eclipse [IStatus](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FIStatus.html) interface has message statuses different from ones usually used in Java. Furthermore the [Status](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FStatus.html) class constructor allows for plugin specific code to be provided, but there is no description how it should be used.
What is the recommended way to print debug and trace messages from Eclipse plugin?

Edit: I am specifically interested in logging Trace and Debug messages, since IStatus allows only for OK, INFO, WARNING, ERROR and CANCEL.
It is also not clear when OK and CANCEL should be used.

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_the_platform_debug_tracing_facility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ILog` interface logs `IStatus` objects in the main Eclipse log (the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory).

If your plugin has an Activator derived from `Plugin` (or `AbstractUIPlugin`) you can get the `ILog` interface for your plugin using the `getLog()` method of `Plugin`.

You can also use

```java
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");

ILog log = Platform.getLog(bundle);
```

`IStatus` is used in several contexts. The `OK` and `CANCEL` status codes are used when `IStatus` is used to indicate the result of an operation, they are not really used for logging.

Note: The `ILog` interface always logs everything it is given, there is no way to enable or disable different levels of logging.

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted to ask. I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: Added a bit more about IStatus, but if you want tracing you can turn on / off this is not the thing to use.